# BASH awk field separator to perform calculation

Tags: bash, awk

I basically have a text file containing data which consists of times in this format

```
(00:00)
(06:08)
(07:54)
```

I've done my share of research to determine how to take only specifically those times (filtering out all the other gunk), and even separating them using awk. The problem occurs when I attempt to add the digits. I seem to be getting a single digit 0 value...

My code is as follows:

```
cat somefile.txt | awk -F: '/([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])/{total+=$1}END{print total}'
```

Note: I am using brackets because the file contains other times, NOT enclosed in brackets... So i've attempted to get rid of the unwanted data, leaving me with only the above portions (00:00)

I'm trying to add the left portion together, which should obviously in this example result in a total of 13.

Really hope I can find a solution, and I'm sure it's something that is not exactly coming to my mind at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

try this line:

```
awk -F'[(:]' '{h+=$2}END{print h}' file
```

example:

```
kent$  echo "(00:00)
(06:08)
(07:54)"|awk -F'[(:]' '{h+=$2}END{print h}' 
13
```

**EDIT**

`[(:]` (I really want to type `:)` ) defines two FS (field separator)s `(` or `:`  so the line would be:

```
(06:08)
field 1 - ""
field 2 - 06
field 3 - 08)
```

if you want to get only minutes, you need to add `)` to your FS too, otherwise you got `$3` with the ending `)`.

Comment: So by stating $2, we are saying the second parameter (to the right of) bracket ? So if I put $2, I'll get the addition of the minutes as well? Sorry, maybe should've mentioned that too. Left side is hours, right is minutes. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: @Stryk9 I added a short explanation, hope it helps.